# Define object method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make my custom object in javascript. I have made a method in my object to make value uppercase but it is not working. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDVmc/)

```
function mystring (name,uppercase){
this.name= name;
this.uppercase= function (){
return this.toUpperCase();
};

}
var jj= new mystring('mycompany');
 jj=jj.uppercase();
console.log(jj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
function mystring (name,uppercase){
    this.name= name;
    this.uppercase= function (){
        return this.name.toUpperCase();
    };

}
var jj= new mystring('mycompany');
jj=jj.uppercase();
console.log(jj);
```

You forgot the `this.name` in the `this.uppercase` function

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert to the entire object to upper case, if you check the console it tells you that the element has no method `toUpperCase`. Instead convert the string, not the object.

```
return this.name.toUpperCase();
```